# How to create average curve in a data frame in R where data contain { }?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in the following format in R and I would like to calculate the average curve of all 'readings' with standard error bars, but I get errors probably due to the format of the readings ({ }). How can I fix this?

Note (update): The size of the df is over 9 mio objects (where there are many readings for each installnr). Do you have any proposal which would run easily in a huge data frame like this?

```
       installnr readdate   readings
    1    002345 2014-08-17 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0}
    2    002345 2014-08-18 {0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}
    3    002345 2014-08-19 {0,1,2,1,0,1,1,1,2,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,1,1,0}
    4    013459 2014-08-17 {1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,3,1,0,0,1,1}
    5    127465 2014-08-19 {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1}
```

Comment: what is your attempted code and what is the class of `readings` ?

Comment: The class of readings is 'factor'. I am trying sapply or mean(a$readings, na.rm=TRUE).

Comment: please `dput()` your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to reflect that request is for *column* means.

You need to convert these lists to character, remove the {}, split into lists and convert to numeric.  The easiest way to get the column means is to form this into a matrix, then just use colMeans.

```
df$readings = gsub("[{}]", "", as.character(df$readings))
Read1 = strsplit(df$readings, ",")
Readings = matrix(as.numeric(unlist(Read1)), nrow=length(Read1))
colMeans(Readings)
 [1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.0 1.0 0.8 0.8 0.6 1.0 0.8 0.6 0.8 0.4 0.8 0.6 0.4 1.0
[20] 0.4 0.8 0.6 0.6 0.6
```

Since you want error bounds, I will mention that you can get the Standard Deviations for the columns from

```
apply(Readings, 2, sd)
 [1] 0.4472136 0.4472136 0.4472136 0.4472136 0.8944272 0.0000000 1.7320508
 [8] 0.4472136 0.4472136 0.5477226 0.7071068 0.8366600 0.5477226 0.8366600
[15] 0.5477226 0.4472136 0.5477226 0.5477226 1.2247449 0.5477226 0.4472136
[22] 0.8944272 0.5477226 0.5477226
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That calculates the mean per row. What if I want to calculate the mean across all 5 rows per hour (each column of the reading)?

Comment: I get the error message: In matrix(as.numeric(unlist(Read1)), nrow = length(Read1)) : data length is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows   and the colMeans gives me 25 elements instead of 24. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I just went back through this. I get that Read1 has 5 rows of 24 elements each. Could you try `sapply(Read1, length)` and say what you get?

Comment: Since the data is too big, I get the following : [1] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
  [26] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
  [51] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
  ......
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 9015082 entries ]]

Comment: Nine million!  Wow.   OK,  maybe better to try `table(sapply(Read1, length))`

Comment: '    24      25      26      27      28      29      30      31      32      33      34 ;
     8933782   13384      38      11      11       8      10      11       8      18      16 ;
     35      36      37      38      39      40      41      42      43      44      45 ;
     99      11      16      16      13      34      13      40      14      60      30 ;
     46      47      48      49      50      52      54      68      96      97     112  '

Comment: '    48    1006   63546      17     103       1       1       1      12       2       1 ;
    123     134     222     224     233     244     257     266     274     277     278 ;
      6       1       2       1       1       4       1      46       8     104      10 ;
    281     283     284     285     286     288     289 ;
      1       1       1       1       1    3497      15 '

Comment: The above table is what I now get. It did not fit in one single comment, that's why I splitted it up.

Comment: Understood the multiple comments. So most of the entries are have length 24, but a few are not.

Comment: I see. Any help on how the above code could run more efficiently in this case is welcome.